# Refresh external data from API call in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, api, activerecord, crud

So I managed to create and persist my car objects with the data from the API to my Postgres db. The question I'm having now, is there a way to update/refresh/rebuild this data once it has been created?

The application will be a simple CRUD application, where the user will be able to create a car collection. So the user will be able to select and add cars from an existing list (`seeds.rb` file) and add them to a collection.

#### services/external_car_api.rb

```
class ExternalCarApi
  include HTTParty

  def self.call
    HTTParty.get("https://api.mycar.com")
  end
end
```

#### db/seeds.rb

```
response = ExternalCarApi.call
response.each do |car|
  Car.create(
    model: car["model"],
    price_usd: car["price_usd"],
  )
end
```

Comment: ideally your api should return id for a specific car, then you have to create update endpoint, e.g /api/cars/1

Comment: The answer to your question is 'yes'. There is a way. In fact, there is more than one way.